# Should a user be allowed to edit their question to the point where it becomes pointless?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/84489/which-targaryen-woman-foresaw-doom-of-valyria) was originally caused by the asker not paying attention to what they were watching, and then [posting a question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/revisions/84489/2) that featured a quote which barely resembled what was actually said.

But now [they have edited their question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/revisions/84489/4), and ended up with one that is basically pointless.

I'm tempted to rollback their edit, even though technically their edit didn't invalidate the answer. Should this be done?

Answer (score 2):

> Should a user be allowed to edit their question to the point where it becomes pointless?

Of course not (and this despite the awkwardly *pointed* turn of phrase).

That said, in this case, has it been edited into a condition where the question has no point? Depends I suppose on how you are using the term, "point"? Does the question have ***value*** to the SE.movies&TV community? I'm not so sure it does, but I don't think that rolling back the edits will increase the value to the community, nor afford it finer point.

Seeing as Aenar only has one daughter, the answer is a simple matter of deduction. Is the answer included in the text of the film they were watching (and we cannot presume that the OP has the luxury of simply watching it again)? I don't know. That said, however, the question is poorly researched (a simple online search reveals the answer, e.g. [Aenar has only the one daughter](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aenar_Targaryen), and it really concerns what is just a matter of trivia, (especially trivial if the answer is not included in the text of the film already, i.e. not pertinent to the narrative). IMHO, the current state of the question is the most clear and useful of all the edits thus far. I see no gain from rolling back the edits.